# Bootstrap Angular 2 on DOM element like in Angular 1

Tags: typescript, angular

Is it possible to `bootstrap Angular 2 on a DOM element` like Angular 1? In Angular 1 this made it for example possible to change the title tag in the `<head>`. In Angular 2 it seems you need to add `my-app` to the `<html>` tag. I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/23A19xQ8R87D0l4QTbnt?p=preview) where you have both Angular 1 and Angular 2 bootstrapped.

***Angular 1***

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['plunker']);
});
```

---

***Angular 2***

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from './app';

bootstrap(App, [])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing the title there is the [Title](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/Title-class.html) service. You can inject it and use it to manipulate the title.

Direct support to modify more than just the title is planned.

Adding `my-app` to `<html>` won't work well in Angular because it wipes the HTML that's within the tag that matches the selector of your root component.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The title tag was an example. What about if you have two angular 2 components in the index.html. Like <my-app></my-app> and <my-other-app></my-other-app> how can I get Angular 2 to bootstrap both in one bootstrap. Not do bootstrap(appname) for all components I guess?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bootstrap both in one bootstrap". If you have two root elements (two components in `index.html`) they are two different Angular2 applications. There are workarounds to share an `Injector` instance though (not tried myself but saw it mentioned).

Comment: Well in Angular 1 you could just add a controller to a div in the index.html and another controller to another div and let them communicate through a service for example. Or even just write {{1 + 2}} in the DOM and it would be picked up by Angular. You didn't have to wrap it in an `my-app` container/component.

Comment: You can easily share a service to communicate but otherwise, Angular2 changed quite a few things. Most things for performance reasons.